# TableRow image background android

Tags: android, xml, image

I'm using an image as the background to a `TableRow` in my android layout, the problem is that the image is too big so the `TableRow` gets stretched.

Is there a way to limit the size of the `TableRow`?

Comment: have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use a fixed size for the `TableRow` or use a smaller image.

Comment: I tried changing to `android:layout_height="110dp"` but it didn't work

Comment: yes, don't know how it's possible. I've also set the value to 10dp just to be sure, and it still was bigger.

Comment: how are you using that tableRow? if you are inflating it, that the layout params might get changed by the system